# How can I use Deepgram in react native expo app

Tags: react-native

How can I use `deepgram` in my `React-Native` project? I was facing an issue using the `deepgram` api to `livestream` from a mobile live audio. It shows

> [Error: Unhandled error. (Expected HTTP 101 response but was '401 Unauthorized')]

This is the code in my (app/index.tsx) I used to implement deepgram in my react native expo app. How can I integrate deepgram?
**the code is given below.**

```js
import { Button, NativeEventEmitter, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import {
  CreateProjectKeyResponse,
  LiveClient,
  LiveTranscriptionEvents,
  createClient,
} from "@deepgram/sdk";

import { Text, View } from "@/components/Themed";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function TabOneScreen() {
  const fetch = require("cross-fetch");
  const eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter();
  const [recording, setRecording] = useState<any>();
  const [recordings, setRecordings] = useState<any>([]);
  const [key, setKey] = useState<any>([]);
  const [permissionResponse, requestPermission] = Audio.usePermissions();
  const [apiKey, setApiKey] = useState<CreateProjectKeyResponse | null>();
  const [connection, setConnection] = useState<LiveClient | null>();
  const [caption, setCaption] = useState<string | null>();
  const [isListening, setListening] = useState(false);
  const deepgram = createClient("DEEPGRAM_API_KEY");
  async function startRecording() {
    try {
      if (permissionResponse?.status !== "granted") {
        console.log("Requesting permission..");
        await requestPermission();
      }
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      });
      const { recording } = await Audio.Recording.createAsync(
        Audio.RecordingOptionsPresets.HIGH_QUALITY
      );
      setRecording(recording);
      console.log("Recording started");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Failed to start recording", err);
    }
  }

  async function stopRecording() {
    setRecording(undefined);

    await recording?.stopAndUnloadAsync();
    let allRecordings = [...recordings];
    const { sound, status } = await recording?.createNewLoadedSoundAsync();
    allRecordings.push({
      sound: sound,
      duration: getDurationFormatted(status.durationMillis),
      file: recording.getURI(),
    });
    setConnection(deepgram.listen.live({ model: "nova", smart_format: true }));
    connection?.on(LiveTranscriptionEvents.Open, () => {
        connection.on(LiveTranscriptionEvents.Close, () => {
          console.log("Connection closed.");
        });
    
        connection.on(LiveTranscriptionEvents.Metadata, (data) => {
          console.log(data);
        });
    
        connection.on(LiveTranscriptionEvents.Transcript, (data) => {
          console.log(data);
        });
      });
    setRecordings(allRecordings);
  }

  function getDurationFormatted(milliseconds: number) {
    const minutes = milliseconds / 1000 / 60;
    const seconds = Math.round((minutes - Math.floor(minutes)) * 60);
    return seconds < 10
      ? `${Math.floor(minutes)}:0${seconds}`
      : `${Math.floor(minutes)}:${seconds}`;
  }

  function getRecordingLines() {
    return recordings.map((recordingLine: any, index: number) => {
      return (
        <View key={index} style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.fill}>
            Recording #{index + 1} | {recordingLine.duration}
          </Text>
          <Button
            onPress={async () => await recordingLine.sound.replayAsync()}
            title="Play"
          ></Button>
        </View>
      );
    });
  }
  

  function clearRecordings() {
    setRecordings([]);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Record Audio</Text>
      <View
        style={styles.separator}
        lightColor="#aae"
        darkColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.1)"
      />
      <Button
        title={recording ? "Stop Recording" : "Start Recording"}
        onPress={recording ? stopRecording : startRecording}
      />
      {getRecordingLines()}
      {recordings.length > 0 ? (
        <Button title={"Clear Recordings"} onPress={clearRecordings} />
      ) : (
        <View />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  separator: {
    marginVertical: 30,
    height: 1,
    width: "80%",
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 40,
  },
  fill: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 15,
  },
});
```